# Get vertical (z) resolution of a DEM raster file (using gdal & python)?

Tags: python, resolution, raster, gdal

I would like to find the vertical (z) resolution of a DEM (digital elevation model) raster.

Using gdal, I can easily find the x and y resolution and pixel width:

```
dem = gdal.Open('DEMraster50.tif')    #DEM is a rectangular tif 
ncol = dem.RasterXSize                #number of columns (aka number of cells along x axis)
nrow = dem.RasterYSize                #number of rows (aka number of cells along y axis)
ulx, pixelwidthx, xskew, uly, yskew, pixelheighty = dem.GetGeoTransform() 
#get resolution and coordinate info (for some reason the order of skew and pixel size is flipped for y axis?!)
```

I can also find the min and max z values (elevations in meters):

```
srcband = dem.GetRasterBand(1)        #get the first band (with the elevation data)
zmin,zmax,zmean,zstdv = srcband.GetStatistics(True, True)  #get stats for this band (automatically ignores nan values)
```

But what I want is the equivalent of nrows and pixel width, in the z direction. 
Is that possible? If so how?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I have a crappy camera sorry, but this might help. I'm looking for nlay and z thickness.
[image: rastergrid]

Comment: There is no equivalent here. What *are* you really looking for? There could be an equivalent if the file had multiple layers (values per grid cell) and they represented something like depth, elevation, or time --- but that is not part of the gdal data model (or most file types) so you could not get direct access to that.

Comment: What I'm hoping for is something like the contour interval on a topo map. I'd like to know the vertical resolution, both how far apart the elevation values are from each other (similar to the pixel width), and how many different elevation values there are in total (similar to the number of cells in the x or y direction, or to bins in a histogram kind of). I assume this is dependent on the original measurement method, but I don't know the source of the DEM file I have, so I can't just look up the instrument specs. Does that clarify?

Comment: Note: I think that if I could get just the "contour spacing", aka the equivalent of pixel width, I could calculate the number of elevation values by looking at the min and max elevations and dividing the difference by the spacing. Or vice versa to find the spacing if I could get just the number of different values.

Comment: I believe that the best library to do this is whitebox-tools: https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools